# iphone quartz draw border around line

Tags: iphone, dictionary, line, border, quartz-2d

what's the best way to draw a (black) border around a line in quartz for iphone? I'm drawing lines on streets on map and if the line is yellow (which is a legit use case), it blends in with the street color. One thing I could do is lay my lines over a little thicker black line, but this doesn't sound very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

> One thing I could do is lay my lines over a little thicker black line, but this doesn't sound very efficient.

I'd say that's the best way to go, unless you have hard proof about it being inefficient. I doubt that though. Stroking and filling a custom shape is probably harder to implement, and likely less efficient stroking one path twice with two different stroke widths (and colors).